# sql sever database user role permission keeps reverting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, user-roles

In my work, I help to set a database users' role as member of  'db_datawriter' and 'db_datareader'.

Once in a while, this user's role will be reverted and shown as only member of 'db_datarwriter' (no longer a member of db_datareader). So I have to change the settings each time when the user approaches to me saying he can't query the database. This could happen several times a day, why the setting keeps getting reverted in this way?

Comment: @Austin correct, i assigned both role, but only db_datareader is reverted. I am sure no other admins are removing roles, but the user is an AD group with name 'domain/XYZDatabase_datawriter', does this name convention has any impacts?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that something, or someone, is removing that permission, @Kay . Maybe they are dropping and recreating the `USER` (and adding just the `db_datawriter` role). Maybe they are removing the `USER` from the `ROLE`. SQL Server doesn't revert such things on it's own.

Comment: Perhaps asking strangers to guess might be less useful than asking the other members of your admin team for help and suggestions. And _"Once in a while"_ is not quite consistent with _"This could happen several times a day"_. Frustration can lead to exaggeration - so which is it? Is there a pattern?

Comment: Maybe you have a script that recreates the server when you publish changes, and it is not copying the permissions correctly